# Rails4 Strong params throws NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I encountered a strange behavior on one computer only.

When strong params are called like this (example taken from SessionController but it fails everywhere where strong params are used)

```
params.require(:session).permit(:email, :password, :remember)
```

I receive the following error:

```
NoMethodError
private method `require' called for<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x000001103230c8>
```

The code works fine on any other computer(developer and production systems) and also worked on this one before. I am using Mac OS(10.9), Ruby(2.2.0), Rails(4.2.x). I use rbenv as ruby version manager.

It has to be an issue with my local installation. After the problem occured, i reinstalled rails, tried another ruby version, updated all the related tools.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails prior to 4.x the controller's params object is a hash with indifferent access whilst in Rails 4+ is an ActionController::Parameters instance. Therefore I suspect the Rails version that is being used in that machine for that project is prior to 4.x.

If rails --version outputs something unexpected try reinstalling all gems as defined by your Gemfile.lock by running:

```
bundle exec gem pristine --all
```

in the root folder of your project.

Comment: Reinstalling the gems solved the problem, I don't understand why the problem occured suddenly.